# Where is this pointer actually pointing?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to learn c using learncodethehardway c book. In ex19 I have the following code:

```
int Monster_init(void *self)
{
  Monster *monster = self;
  monster->hit_points = 10;
  return 1;
}

int Monster_attack(void *self, int damage)
{
  Monster *monster = self;

  printf("You attack %s!\n", monster->proto.description);

  monster->hit_points -= damage;

  if(monster->hit_points > 0) {
    printf("It is still alive.\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("It is dead.\n");
    return 1;
  }
}

Object MonsterProto = {
  .init = Monster_init,
  .attack = Monster_attack
};
```

This is the Object structure:

```
typedef struct {
  char *description;
  int (*init)(void *self);
  void (*describe)(void *self);
  void (*destroy)(void *self);
  void *(*move)(void *self, Direction direction);
  int (*attack)(void *self, int damage);
} Object;
```

And this is the Monster structure:

```
struct Monster {
  Object proto;
  int hit_points;
};
```

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around the `Monster_init` and `Monster_attack` functions. I have a `MonsterProto` variable of type Object defined and inside there `.init` is set to the `Monster_init`function and `.attack` is set to the `Monster_attack` function.

I think I understand the notion of `void` in terms of declaring a function that has side effects but doesn't need to return something. What I don't understand is what exactly is the void *self pointer pointing at and why does it allow me to call a function with no arguments? What is the purpose of the self pointer?

I didn't want to include too much code here but if this is not enough context to answer the question, then you can find all the [code here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html).

I appreciate any pointers in the right direction; nu pun intended :)

Comment: `self` is the address of the `struct Monster` that you pass to those functions. Each of those functions operates on an individual object, and passing in the pointer to that object is how they know which one to work on. Not sure where you're getting "call a function with no arguments" from.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I think I understand what you mean. I got confused on the init pointer function from inside the Object struct. But I now realize that ``.init = Monster_init`` is not actually calling a function with no arguments but it's just saying that we have a pointer that should point to that particular function. Therefore as you said the self becomes the address of the ``struct Monster``. Thanks! If you'd like to post this as a response I will accept the answer.

Comment: OK, I see where you were going. Yes, you're right about `.init` being a function pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be effectively implementing a kind of object-oriented approach.

`self` is the address of the `struct Monster` that you pass to those functions. Each of those functions operates on an individual object, and passing in the pointer to that object is how they know which one to work on.

This:

```
.init = Monster_init,
```

is not "calling a function with no arguments" - the `init` member of your `struct` is a pointer to a function returning an `int` and accepting a single `void *` parameter, and that line assigns the address of `Monster_init()` to it. This way, if you have a pointer to an object, you can call `int n = myobject->proto.init(&myobject);` or similar without knowing which actual function gets called. With a different object, you might be calling a different function with the same line of code.